# Align 3 RadioButtons in RadioGroup Horizontally as left, center, right in Android

Tags: android

How to align 3 radio buttons (with dimensions wrap_content) in a Radio Group (with dimensions match_parent) horizontally

Answer (score 0):

- Set Radio Group width to match_parent or in dip whatever width you want
- Add View (dummy view) in between two radio buttons i.e between 1st and 2nd & between 2nd and 3rd, with android:layout_weight="1"

  ```
          <RadioGroup
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="60dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:background="@drawable/shape_bg_view_common"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtSearch">

              <RadioButton
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                  android:background="@null"
                  android:button="@drawable/slctr_all"/>
              <Space
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"/>

              <RadioButton
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@null"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"
                  android:button="@drawable/slctr_many"/>

              <Space
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"/>

              <RadioButton
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                  android:background="@null"
                  android:button="@drawable/slctr_few"/>
          </RadioGroup>
  ```
- Space can also be used in place of View

  ```
     <Space
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"/>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the orientation in Radiogroup to horizontal

```
    <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Radio button 1"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Radio button 2"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Radio button 3"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: The problem with the above solution is , all the radio button will be aligned in center , which is not required .The first RadioButton should be in left , second should be in center and third should be in right. I have solved the issue. Below is my answer